# Why is linux used for IoT devices

Tags: embedded-system

I know that linux provides some benefits when it comes to security, and cost. But why is Linux used so much for embedded systems and IoT devices?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. The question you've asked is going to result in a lot of opinions rather than answers, which goes against the Q&A nature of AskUbuntu. Perhaps this question could be asked on [UbuntuForums](https://ubuntuforums.org) or a conversational site? 

Comment: Seems like the first sentence offers a plausible answer to the question posed in the second sentence. This suggests that the question may not be well-researched.

Answer (score 1):

Linux runs well on all kinds of ARM devices. In addition to that Ubuntu is user-friendly and well-supported by the Ubuntu user community, so it's a logical choice for embedded systems and IoT devices.